# Lenovo x230 wifi and hdd light not working

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, x230

I just did a fresh install of 14.04.2 and my wifi and hdd lights are now not working.

Does anyone know what the problem could be or how i could fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks